# ElasticSearch MetricBeat mapping issue

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I have installed MetricBeat on my Windows system. And started it. In the configuration metricbeats.yml I have set the elasticsearch property as follows

```
output.elasticsearch:
_ # Array of hosts to connect to._
_ hosts: [“10.193.164.145:9200”]_
_ template.name: “metricbeat”_
_ template.path: “metricbeat.template.json”_
_ template.overwrite: false_
```

Now when I start my MetricBeat, I repeatedly get this message in the logs

```
Can not index event (status=400): "MapperParsingException[mapping [default]]; nested: MapperParsingException[No handler for type [keyword] declared on field [hostname]]; "
```

What is the issue here?

Is it due to compatibility? My ElasticSearch version is 1.4.x and MetricBeats is 5.5.x

Please do let me know.

Comment: Not sure if it is a compatibility issue. Cannot see 1.4 in compatibility matrix -  https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#show_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

1.4 doesn't seem to be supported anymore.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/metricbeat-compatibility-with-elasticsearch/99213

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is any matrix right now who support elastic 1.x series with 5.x metrixbeat. but 
you can cross check compatibility matrix here 
[product compatibility matrix](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility)

you can check below document also for your reference. Not sure this might be helpful to your problem.
[elastic product end of life dates](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol)